# Is it possible to infer ambient temperature from battery temperature?

Tags: battery, sensors, temperature

A few questions here and at Stack Overflow make battery temperature available for the inquiring minds:

- [Get temperature of battery on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997289/get-temperature-of-battery-on-android/3997349#3997349)
- [How does Android obtain battery temperature](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29405/how-does-android-obtain-battery-temperature)

Yet, I'm curious if there's a method for deriving ambient temperature from battery data. A [quick search](http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html) at U.S. Patents and Trademarks' Office revealed no such patents (yet).

Comment: What's your question? Whether it's possible to make an accurate guess, whether an app exists that does this, or how to find the ambient temperature on your phone without such a sensor?

Comment: All three :) Updating the question.

Comment: This site works best if you ask one specific question; otherwise, you run the risk that someone knows the answer to only one of your three questions and doesn't answer. Of your three questions, only the third (how) seems on-topic for the site: whether it's possible is nothing to do with Android, and "is there an app for x" questions are discouraged.

Comment: @DanHulme - fixed again. Will move "an app for that" to SoftwareRecs.