# How can an NFC battery's NFC functionality be used on Android devices?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery, nfc

My Samsung Galaxy SIII comes with a battery with an Near Field Communications (NFC) label on it. Several earlier Android modles don't come with such a label on the battery. I would like to know what the NFC functionality on the battery enables Android devices and their OS to do with the battery.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "how can it be used?" Are you looking for a list of every OS feature that leverages NFC? A list of every app that uses NFC? Something else entirely? Such lists would be too broad for an SE question, I would say. If you just want to know *why* the battery is relevant, that's answered by [Why is the NFC in the Galaxy Nexus battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25480/why-is-the-nfc-in-the-galaxy-nexus-battery) The answer is that it's just an antenna. nothing more.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. As I need to get a replacement battery, I guess I will have to get one with the NFC label then if I want the NFC on my device to work. The original battery is a 2100mAh battery which used to charge in 4 hours and last several days, but now, about a year and a half later, once the battery level reaches 47% the device powers off, and charging only lasts 2 hours, hence the need for a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batteries labeled NFC come with the NFC antenna, without which it would be impossible for the NFC chip on the device to operate.